# How to get name of document libraries from SharePoint 2010 site to text file

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to get name of all document libraries from SharePoint 2010 site to text file using PowerShell script.
Can anyone provide me some pointers?

PFB the snippet I have tried to get list on console:

```
Get-SPWeb http://mysites/sites/ITEquipment |
   Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
   Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPDocumentLibrary" } |
    Select Title
```

I want the list to be saved in a text file

Comment: It could be helpful : http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint/windows-powershell-scripts-sharepoint-info-files-pagesweb-parts

Comment: Thanks Amit, I got that thing but I did need them in a text file. I have edited my question